# 4.7.1 API query for contributions in same year returns no results

Tags: api, contributions, issues

This worked correctly in 4.6.8, but not in 4.7.0 or 4.7.1.  This query returns no results:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contribution', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'receive_date' => array('BETWEEN' => array("2016-01-01", "2016-03-31")),
));
```

But this one does return contributions from 2016:

```
$result = civicrm_api3('Contribution', 'get', array(
  'sequential' => 1,
  'receive_date' => array('BETWEEN' => array("2015-12-31", "2016-03-31")),
));
```

As far as I can tell, any query for contributions in the same year returns no results.  Is this a bug?

Comment: does the second one returns correctly all the contributions you expect? it does seems strange indeed

Comment: Without doing an exhaustive comparison...yes, the second one seems to find all 100+ contributions correctly.